# Replace tag inside tag using RegEx

Tags: regex

I would like to replace a tag inside a tag using RegEx

```
<script>alert('this is a sample alert <script>document.write(getURLParameter('model'))</script> and some other text here');</script>
```

to

```
<script>alert('this is a sample alert " + getURLParameter('model') + " and some other text here');</script>
```

I have more than 1,000 files need to correct using Dreamweaver "Find and Replace" wiht "Use Regular Expression" to match all occurrence

Comment: are those 2 `<script />` tags the only tags that will ever occur in your input?  because if they're not, then you might want to think twice about using regex

Comment: @SamIam yes only 1 script tag inside a script tag

Answer (score 0):

Find `(<script>[\s\S]+?)(<script>document.write\()([\s\S]+?)(\)<\/script>)([\s\S]+?<\/script>)`

Replace with `$1" + $3 + "$5`

EDIT: Also included `document.write`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Its hard to tell what's constant from your example.

Find:

```
(?s)(<script>.*?)<script>.*?\((.+?)\)</script>(.*?</script>)
```

Replace:

```
$1' + $2 + '$3
```